# Naming convention for getting collection size

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I have the following class

```
class X {
    private List<Calendar> calendars;

//    public int getCalendarCount()
//    public int getCalendarSize()
//    public int getSize()
//    public int getCount()
//    public int size()
//    public int count()
}
```

I was wondering, what is the most common used naming convention, to retrieve the calendas' size.

In [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size%28%29), they are using `size`.

However, in some 3rd parties library like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/HierarchicalStreamReader.html#getAttributeCount%28%29), they are using getXXXCount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `X` is only about holding a list of calendars, then `size` would make sense — but then that would beg the question of why you're creating a class as opposed to just using `List<Calendar>`.

If `X` is going to hold much of anything else, then presumably it's going to provide a means of accessing the `List` of `Calendars`, so it doesn't really need a method to give that list's size (since `List` already has it). That would be the usual thing.

But if you're not directly exposing that `List` for some reason (and remember, you can make it an [unmodifiable `List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29)), then I'd probably go with `getCalendarCount`.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the actual name of X.

I would opt for getCalendarCount() unless your class is named something like CalendarList in which case something like getSize may be appropriate.

There's no real convention as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

There are no hard-and-fast conventions on whether to use `size` versus `count` versus `length`, and whether or not to use `getXxx` versus `xxx`.

The best advice I can offer is:

- to try to be consistent, and
- use the `getXxx` convention if there is a possibility that your class may be used as a "bean".